# Skipping invalid geometries without fixing them in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, geometry, intersection, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon

In QGIS 3.16.14 I have a shapefile with multipolygons (flood risk map of the country) and another layer of points (buildings). I need to identify which of those points are inside those polygons and which are not.

So after researching the internet I tried `Data Management Tools > Join attributes by location`. But it failed, because of invalid geometries.

Then I tried to fix those invalid geometries, by answers to similar issues in this forum. I tried the "Check geometries" plugin, but it stopped responding.
I tried "Simplify" under Geometry tools reducing precision to 1 meter, but the simplified result still contained geometry errors.

I tried `v.clean` and after working overnight, it produced a list of 11 thousand errors, but I didn't know how to proceed. Apparently, those tools struggle because there is really a lot of errors.

Since I do not need a lot of precision, is there some tool in QGIS where I could check if my points are *"approximately"* inside those polygons while ignoring those geometry errors (but not skipping this check)?

Alternatively, if that geometry needs to be fixed, which geometry fixing approach would be most suitable for such a large number of errors, but where I don't need super large precision. Just need to check if a building is roughly in a flood zone or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Try buffering your polygons with 0 distance, sometimes it fixes geometry errors.
- If you want to ignore the invalid geometries, you can set it Options - Processing - General:
  [image]

Comment: Thank you! While "ignoring invalid geometries" apparently was not useful option (since, it ignored completely all features as all contained those errors), the buffering with 0 distance worked and now the resulting layers can be used without problems! It did algorithm processing for several hours until it reached the result so if anyone in future has similar problem and is using this solution, be patient :)

Comment: Yes it is a dangerous setting, nice!

Answer (score 5):

You can use QGIS expression with [overlay](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#overlay-contains) functions: they work even with invalid geometries. To attach to each point the `$id` of the polygon, use this expression (`poly` is the name of the polygon layer):

```
array_to_string(overlay_within('poly', $id))
```

*Two polygons with intentionally invalid geometries. Points are correctly assigned to the polygons they are within, even where polygons overlap. I used the expression above for labelling:*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've had good luck cleaning geometry with the ["Fix Geometries"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#fix-geometries) tool found within the QGIS Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).